# Delete specific policy revision from chef server

Tags: chef-infra

Is there any way to delete specific policy revision from the chef server?

I know there is `chef delete-policy POLICY_NAME (options)`, but this command deletes all revisions, as per docs:

```
chef delete-policy POLICY_NAME (options)  is a command to delete all revisions of the named policy that exist on the Chef server.
```